# PHP script times out - no CURL response received

Tags: php, curl

I'm running a PHP script in which I'm using CURL to pass a parameter to a different PHP script and call it 100 times.

Right now the second function is called successfully about 30 times, but after a while I get a timeout error stating something like "no response received".

Here's the first PHP script that I use to call the second one:

```
<?php
$time_start = time();

for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
$data = array("order_total"=>"test", "enterprise_code"=>2, "order_number"=>"2", "origin"=>"2");
$string = http_build_query($data);

$ch=curl_init($undisclosed-path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); //we are going to use the post method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); //this $string is going to be posted
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

In the second script I'm echo-ing some things each time, so I think there should be a response received... but I guess there isn't...

Is there a way to allow a greater execution time for a PHP script so it won't timeout like that? Or instruct it somehow not to expect any response? In some cases I'm getting an error 500 instead of a timeout.

Thank you.

Comment: `set_time_limit($seconds)`

Comment: But maybe you shouldn't flood the target server with requests.

Comment: I added set_time_limit(10000); at the first line of the first script but I still get an error 500. The second script is still called successfully about 30 times. And there's some indication that the second script is called a few times after I get the error 500.

Comment: I'm still questioning why you need to flood the remote server with 100 requests. If it was my server I would block you.

Comment: It's my server and it should be able to hold many more requests than what I am giving it. I am doing this for testing purposes.

Comment: A HTTP 500 is a general server error code, check the webserver logfiles of the remote server, you can do that since it's yours.

Comment: It seems that your remote server script is taking time, so you need to increase execution time on your remote server as well, in case of 500 , remote server script is not able to process so much request,

Comment: If PHP is running as a CGI (on the cURL client side) Apache may terminate the request if it takes longer than `Timeout` to complete.  This is regardless of what PHP time limits are set in the script.  For example [FcgidIOTimeout](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidiotimeout) or [TimeOut](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout).